# Orbit prediction for satellites using the Kepler model

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, low-earth-orbit, orbital-elements, kepler-telescope

I would like to know how to model the motion of satellites in orbit using Keplerian, i.e. develop a simulation model that tracks paths of satellites using Keplerian orbits in Python?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Satellites are not typically suborbital for very long, one way or another.  Do you mean satellite ground tracks?

Comment: @notovny yes I mean satellite ground tracks

Comment: "teach me to write an orbital mechanics program in python, from scratch" is kind of a tall order for this site. Have you done any work on it on your own?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a tutorial approach look at https://github.com/MovingPlanetsAround/ABIE

If you want a library to model Earth satellites using existing satellite data, take a look at: https://pypi.org/project/sgp4/ This uses a model that includes non-spherical Earth, drag and moon/sun effects if the orbit is large enough for them to matter. This means it is much more than Kepler.

Answer (score 1):

> Orbit prediction for satellites using Kepler model

Okay I'll give you a short answer to help get you started.

There are two general categories for solving position as a function of time for satellites in Earth orbit.

- [Kepler orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit) and some slowly varying perturbation approximations on those such as atmospheric drag (most common/universal is [SGP4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_perturbations_models) using [TLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set)s as inputs)
- Direct [numerical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) of the [orbital state vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_state_vectors) $[x, y, z, v_x, v_y, v_z]$ or written as position and velocity vectors, just $[\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{v}]$)

Both ways have advantages and disadvantages.

#### Kepler orbits

For satellites bound to Earth, Kepler orbits will be ellipses. Know that this is a pretty significant approximation because Earth's gravity field is not spherically symmetric, there's a big equatorial bulge caused by Earth's spinning which causes orbits to precess pretty quickly. For example, the 51.6° inclination of the International Space Station's orbit with respect to Earth's equator causes its orbital plane to precess around the Earth every 50 days or so, modulating the amount of darkness astronauts experience when it goes into Earth's shadow and the load on the stations batteries when the's no solar power generation.

That's a great example of why Kepler orbits for satellites generally have perturbation corrections added on before they are actually useful or predictive. Another is that the station is constantly losing altitude (and picking up speed) due to atmospheric drag even at ~400 km above the Earth, thanks in part to those big solar panels. So you've got to keep changing your semimajor axis steadily if you want your Kepler model to be useful and predictive.

However, *the rate* that you drop the altitude and pick up speed depends on the mood of the Sun! The solar wind and other charged particle bursts from the Sun heat the atmosphere causing it to rise up and increase the drag on all the satellites in low Earth orbit (LEO).

So in the end we just look up those TLE's and use SGP4 (linked above) which has some of these perturbations built in through special coefficients calculated for the TLEs by satellite trackers (government and amateur).

And those folks use numerically integrated orbits to extract those TLEs.

For Kepler orbits, you can not get the position as a function of time without further approximations, but you can get time as a function of position fairly simply, then invert it.

This has been discussed in detail more several times on this site - if you are interested let me know and I'll try to find some links here to those posts.

#### Direct numerical integration

This may seem harder at first, but the insight it gives you and the skills to solve other problems in the future makes it worth it!

- Invert $\mathbf{F} = m\mathbf{a}$ to get $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{F}/m$
- Calculate $\mathbf{a}$ from a model of Earth's gravitational force, which has a central $1/r^2$ (actually $-\mathbf{\hat{r}}/|r|^2$ or more conveniently $-\mathbf{r}/|r|^3$) component and a big [quadrupole moment expressed as $J_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geopotential_model#Largest_terms) Of course there's an infinite number of coefficients because Earth is lumpy on all scales, but these are the main ones to get you started.
- Say $d\mathbf{v}/dt = \mathbf{F}/m$ and $d\mathbf{x}/dt = \mathbf{v}$ and put those into any [differential equation initial valule problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem) solver. For Python for example that would be [`scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html)

Once again, this has been discussed in detail more several times on this site - if you are interested let me know and I'll try to find some links here to those posts.

Comment: Thanks a lot @uhoh for the feedback, I want to use the first method for Kepler orbit but I want to build just a simple model in python, I will just ignore atmospheric drag that's why I think I will not even need SGP4 using TLEs, just as you said "For Kepler orbits, you can not get the position as a function of time without further approximations, but you can get time as a function of position fairly simply, then invert it" and I will consider the circle path as eccentricity it will be zero for my case, major axis constant, just I need that, how to program that simple model in Python?

Comment: hi Uhoh, can you send me more details on kepler orbit as i m interested on the 1st option of using kepler orbit. Thanks.

Comment: @RackyAlvin there's a LOT of information you can find in various questions and answers on this site and in Astronomy SE as well. In Stack Exchange we don't really connect by email etc. Post more (god) questions based on what you've learned so far, and likely more answers will follow. But you've got to do the driving by reading, trying, thinking and then asking again. Good luck *and enjoy!*

Comment: @RackyAlvin But you can take a look at my question in the meta section of this site [Do "calculate satellite orbits" questions need a canonical community wiki like Astronomy SE's "...find positions of the planets...and visualize them?"](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3063/12102) and use the links at the bottom of my question to find LOTS of python example - especially the last two links to `odeint` and `solve_ivp`. Sorry I didn't see your May 21 comment for some reason, I'm responding now.